# How to read data from one table and copy into other using the WSO2 DAS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

We are working on the ETL. I am able to insert data into table using streams in **DATA ANALYTICS SERVER**.  But I'm unable to copy the data from one table into other table. Is there any procedures to be followed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Batch Analytics Script and writing spark queries to select from a DAS table and insert into another DAS table. Please refer the DAS Spark Documentation for more details [1]. Apart from that execution of the script can be scheduled by using cron expressions [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Spark+Query+Language

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Scheduling+Batch+Analytics+Scripts

Comment: Hi Tharik , Thanks for your response.